# Matplotlib: dates don't display correctly formatted

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't manage to display time values correctly on the x-axis.

Here are the pieces of code I use to plot my data:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
plt.plot(times, prices)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_fmt)
plt.savefig('final.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Actually, the DateFormatter seems to have no effect. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code please ?

`times` is a list of datetimes, and `prices` a list of floats.

[image]

Comment: Just for S&G, could you provide a small sample initialization command for input arrays that reproduce the issue? A) I'm lazy, and B) I want to make sure we are playing with the same exact datatypes here.

Comment: Also, what is `mdates`?

Comment: The code in the question is correct and would reproduce the desired plot. If you have a problem, you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: My bad, the plotting code above does work. The working example works as it should. I was trying to create some sort of auto-updating figure, the example was part of a loop. It turns out that I need to ```plt.close()``` the figure each time in order for the date formatter to work.